# Check if textarea is empty always return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created below form with 1 input and 1 textarea. however it seem like the textarea never is empty even though i haven wrote anything in it when i press submit button. What can trigger this??

**form**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">

    <div class="reg_section personal_info">
          <input type="text" name="username" id="title" value="" placeholder="title" required="required">
          <textarea name="textarea" id="description" placeholder="Beskrivelse" required title="3 characters minimum"></textarea>
    </div>


    <div>
        <span class="submit" style="text-align: left; padding: 0 10px;"> <input type="submit"name="commit" value="Tilføj" onclick="saveMarker(document.getElementById('title'), document.getElementById('description'));"></span>
          <span class="submit" style="text-align: right; padding: 0 10px;"><input TYPE="button" name="commit" value="Fortryd" onclick="div_hide();"></span>
        </div>

</form>
```

**Function**

```
function validate() {

  if ($('#description').val() == "" && $('#title').val() == "") {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: How is `validate()` called?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. Your code works just fine. The `validate()` function return `FALSE` if both are empty and `TRUE` if any of them isn't.

Comment: its called `if (validate() == true) {`

Comment: I tested this as well and it works fine for me.  If both are empty false is returned.  If either one or both have content true is returned.

Comment: strange when i try it returns the length of the description is 0 but still return true. it only return false if title is empty

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot =)

```
if(document.getElementById("description").value == '') {

}
```

Comment: Why would this be any different?

Comment: it's vanilla bruh...  no need for a library for users that don't like using them... Like me.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this

```
$.trim( $('#description').val() ).length > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uing   `$('#description').text();`

```
if ($('#description').text() == "" && $('#title').val() == "") {
```

Comment: `$('#description').text()` and `$('#description').val()` should always be identical.